# Problem with Photoshop CS6 Freezing up on OSX Mavericks

Tags: macos, performance, adobe-photoshop

I have a iMac we purchased last year (27inch, 32GB Ram, 512GB Flash Storage, OSX 10.9 Mavericks) with Adobe CS6 installed on it. About 2 months ago our Graphic Designer started having problems where when she went to save a Photoshop file the Mac would freeze up and just show the spinning pinwheel, after this happens we are unable to to even shut the system down and have to resort to holding the power button until it shuts off. Now this doesn't happen every time and we went almost a month with a problem but it has started back up and is happening multiple times a day. We have tried re installing CS6, creating a new profile for the user, deleting the library folder, saving to the desktop instead of a network location but nothing has seemed to do the trick. I'm a Windows Sysadmin so I'm out of my depths here and my poor Graphics Designer is getting really upset. Has anyone out there every had something like this happen??
                         Forever Grateful for any help that could be given -Giles Marsha

Answer (score 1):

I would use opensnoop to figure out what it's doing when it hangs.

I've used the following command to watch a process and log the results to my desktop while watching the results live.

Once your figure out which file it's hanging on, you might be able to determine what the next step should be.

> ps aux | grep -i Photoshop | head -n 1 | col | cut -f 2 | cut -d' ' -f
>   1 | xargs -I {} sudo opensnoop -v -p {} | tee -a ~/Desktop/logfile.txt